# Why do i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML') ,

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
function removeFromTable(date)
{
  let datemf=[];
  let flag=0;
  let flagpos=0;

  datelist=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date'));
  tableList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  ingredientslist=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ing'))
  
// got the date as the original format

// now using the date I removed the datas from all list 

for(let i=0;i<datelist.length;i++)
{
    if (datelist[i] === date )
    {
      datelist.splice(i,1)
    }
}

tableList.forEach((v,i) =>{delete v[date]})
ingredientslist.forEach((a,n) => {delete a[date]})

for(let i=0;i<tableList.length;i++)
{
 
  if(Object.keys(tableList[i]).length==0)
  {
    console.log('working')
    tableList.splice(i,1)
    ingredientslist.splice(i,1)
  }
}
 
// and updated the local storage

localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(tableList))
localStorage.setItem('date',JSON.stringify(datelist))
localStorage.setItem('ing',JSON.stringify(ingredientslist))

//for error handling if somehow a error pops after updation

if(!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('date')) && !JSON.pa

rse(localStorage.getItem('data')) || document.querySelector('.datefromjs').innerHTML== 'undefined') 
{
localStorage.removeItem('date')
localStorage.removeItem('data')
localStorage.removeItem('ing')
}

location.reload();//reloads page
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PlanEatRepeat</title>
</head>
<body onload="addOptionsToPage()">
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: large;">Your Meal Plan</p>
  <div class="datafromjs">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Create A Plan to display</p>
  </div>
  <script src="data2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was attempting to extract the content enclosed within a paragraph element, specifically one with the class datafromjs, using the innerHTML property in JavaScript. This property provides the HTML content within an element.

However, I encountered a situation where the innerHTML of this specific paragraph element was undefined. This could occur if the paragraph element with the class datafromjs doesn’t exist in the document, or if it exists but doesn’t contain any HTML content.

In response to this undefined scenario, I decided to take action by removing data that was previously stored in the localStorage of the browser. localStorage is a type of web storage that allows JavaScript sites and apps to store data right in the browser with no expiration time.
Despite my efforts, I was met with an error during this process

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `.datefromjs` element in your HTML, so `document.querySelector('.datefromjs')` won't be returning anything.

Comment: error is pretty clear, where is that element with the `datefromjs` class in your HTML?

Comment: yes, thank you, I saw that and I feel stupid